# finding the time periods an issuer has not called the service from a given time period

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table that contains the time periods when an issuer calls the service. this table can have overlapping and non overlapping time periods:

```
with mht_issuer_revoked_call (issuerid, startdate, enddate) as (values
(4, to_date('25-11-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('25-11-2022 12:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
(4, to_date('25-11-2022 12:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('26-11-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
(40, to_date('25-11-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('25-11-2022 06:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
(40, to_date('25-11-2022 06:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('25-11-2022 12:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
(40, to_date('25-11-2022 11:30:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('25-11-2022 18:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
(40, to_date('25-11-2022 18:30:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('25-11-2022 19:30:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
(50, to_date('25-11-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('25-11-2022 12:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
(50, to_date('25-11-2022 11:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('26-11-2022 01:30:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
(40, to_date('25-11-2022 19:31:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('26-11-2022', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
(50, to_date('25-11-2022 23:10:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('25-11-2022 23:30:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
(50, to_date('25-11-2022 23:30:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('25-11-2022 23:45:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
(50, to_date('25-11-2022 23:50:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), to_date('25-11-2022 23:55:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
)
```

i managed to merge the time periods and new time periods dont have any overlapping with each other. my output is as follows:

```
with issuer_calls_merged (issuerid, start_date_time, end_date_time) as (values
      (4 ,'11/25/2022' ,             '11/26/2022'),
      (40 ,'11/25/2022',             '11/25/2022 6:00:00 PM'),
      (40 ,'11/25/2022 6:30:00 PM',  '11/25/2022 7:30:00 PM'),
      (40 ,'11/25/2022 7:31:00 PM',  '11/26/2022'           ),
      (50 ,'11/25/2022',             '11/26/2022 1:30:00 AM')
)
```

i am trying to write a procedure that gets FromDate and EndDate as input parameters and for each issuer calculates how many minutes are not covered according to retrieved FromDate and EndDate Parameters.
for example i will give these parameters:
FromDate := '11/20/2022'
EndDate  := '11/28/2022'
then according to inserted time periods in issuer_calls table, for issuerid 40 i expect this output:

```
| issuerid | start_date_time(uncovered) | end_date_time(uncovered) | uncovered_time_minutes
| 40       | 11/20/2022                 | 11/25/2022               | 7200
| 40       | 11/25/2022 6:00:00 PM      | 11/25/2022 6:30:00 PM    | 30
| 40       | 11/25/2022 7:30:00 PM      | 11/25/2022 7:31:00 PM    | 1
| 40       | 11/26/2022                 | 11/28/2022               | 2880
```

i tried to do the job with procedure bellow:

```
create or replace procedure GAP(out_res out sys_refcursor,
                                in_FromDate mht_issuer_revoked_call.startdate%type,
                                in_EndDate  mht_issuer_revoked_call.enddate%type
                                ) AS

                                
BEGIN

**-- i tried to compare the given time period(FromDate-EndDate) with previous merged time periods and calculate the gaps and then union with previous gap**

open out_res for 
  select ut.issuerid,
         ut.startdate,
         ut.enddate,
         ut.initialgap as gap
    from 
    (
      with minStartDate as
      (
          select  r.issuerid,
                  min(r.startdate) as min_StartDate
          from mht_issuer_revoked_call r
          group by r.issuerid
      )
      select m.issuerid,
             in_FromDate as StartDate,
             case
               when m.min_StartDate >= in_EndDate then in_EndDate
               else m.min_StartDate
             end as EndDate,
             case
               when m.min_StartDate >= in_EndDate then (in_EndDate - in_FromDate + 1)*24*60
               else (min_StartDate - in_FromDate + 1)*24*60
             end as initialgap
      from minStartDate m
      
      union all

**--- bellow part merges the time periods and calculate the gaps between them**
    
      SELECT issuerid,
          end_date_time,
          next_row_start,
          (next_row_start - end_date_time)*24*60 as gap
        from 
        ( 
          SELECT issuerid,
                 start_date_time,
                 end_date_time,
                 case 
                   when lead(start_date_time) over(partition by issuerid order by start_date_time) is null then end_date_time
                   else lead(start_date_time) over(partition by issuerid order by start_date_time)
                 end as next_row_start
          FROM   (
            SELECT issuerid,
                   LAG( dt ) OVER ( PARTITION BY issuerid ORDER BY dt ) AS start_date_time,
                   dt AS end_date_time,
                   start_end
            FROM   (
              SELECT issuerid,
                     dt,
                     CASE SUM( value ) OVER ( PARTITION BY issuerid ORDER BY dt ASC, value DESC, ROWNUM ) * value
                       WHEN 1 THEN 'start'
                       WHEN 0 THEN 'end'
                     END AS start_end
              FROM   mht_issuer_revoked_call
              UNPIVOT ( dt FOR value IN ( startdate AS 1, enddate AS -1 ) )
            )
            WHERE start_end IS NOT NULL
          )
          WHERE  start_end = 'end'
    )
    where (next_row_start - end_date_time) > 0
    group by issuerid,next_row_start,end_date_time
    ) ut
    order by ut.issuerid, ut.StartDate;
END gap;
```

but at the end i couldn't achieve the explained result above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I find the gaps between overlapping or non overlapping date ranges in one day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74667324/how-can-i-find-the-gaps-between-overlapping-or-non-overlapping-date-ranges-in-on)

Comment: this link only helps to merge overlapping time periods but now i must compare a given time period with them also

Answer (score 0):

You can get your result using just SQL and process it later. In this answer your FromDate And EndDate (P_FROM, P_UNTILL) are set to those from your question. You can define them as parameters or bind variables so you could change them. Comments are in the code.

```sql
WITH 
    tbl AS    -- sample data
        (
            Select 4  "ID", To_Date('25.11.2022 00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "START_DATE", To_Date('25.11.2022 12:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 4  "ID", To_Date('25.11.2022 12:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "START_DATE", To_Date('26.11.2022 00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 40 "ID", To_Date('25.11.2022 00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "START_DATE", To_Date('25.11.2022 06:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 40 "ID", To_Date('25.11.2022 06:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "START_DATE", To_Date('25.11.2022 12:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 40 "ID", To_Date('25.11.2022 11:30:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "START_DATE", To_Date('25.11.2022 18:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 40 "ID", To_Date('25.11.2022 18:30:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "START_DATE", To_Date('25.11.2022 19:30:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 40 "ID", To_Date('25.11.2022 19:31:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "START_DATE", To_Date('26.11.2022 00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 50 "ID", To_Date('25.11.2022 00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "START_DATE", To_Date('25.11.2022 12:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 50 "ID", To_Date('25.11.2022 11:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "START_DATE", To_Date('26.11.2022 01:30:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 50 "ID", To_Date('25.11.2022 23:10:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "START_DATE", To_Date('25.11.2022 23:30:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 50 "ID", To_Date('25.11.2022 23:30:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "START_DATE", To_Date('25.11.2022 23:45:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "END_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 50 "ID", To_Date('25.11.2022 23:50:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "START_DATE", To_Date('25.11.2022 23:55:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "END_DATE" From Dual 
        ), 
    day_tbl AS          -- create CTE to prepare your data
        (  Select   ID, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By ID Order By START_DATE) "RN",    -- ordering ID events
                    START_DATE "START_DATE", To_Char(START_DATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') "START_TIME",    -- just showing the time part of START_DATE
                    END_DATE "END_DATE", To_Char(END_DATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') "END_TIME",            -- just showing the time part of END_DATE
                    --
                    To_Date('20.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "P_FROM",       -- column with P_FROM  - you could define it as bind variable
                    To_Date('28.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "P_UNTILL",     -- column with P_FROM  - you could define it as bind variable
                    (  END_DATE - START_DATE  ) * 24 * 60 "MINS"        -- first calculation used for first and last row
            From 
                (Select *
                 From   (                       -- for each ID create starting and ending row and  union them with your data
                            Select ID "ID", START_DATE "START_DATE", END_DATE "END_DATE" From tbl Union ALL
                            Select ID, To_Date('20.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), Min(START_DATE) From tbl GROUP BY ID Union All      -- row with P_FROM as START_DATE - you could define it as bind variable
                            Select ID, Max(END_DATE), To_Date('28.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From tbl GROUP BY ID          -- row with P_UNTILL as END_DATE - you could define it as bind variable
                        )
                Order By ID, START_DATE
                ) 
        )
SELECT 
    *   -- you can select just the columns you need (not all of them like here)
FROM
    (   Select 
            ID, RN, START_DATE, START_TIME, END_DATE, END_TIME, P_FROM, P_UNTILL,
            CASE WHEN RN = 1 Or RN = Max(RN) OVER(Partition By ID) THEN MINS        -- first and last row already calculated
        -- else --> second calculation for rows that are not first nor last
            ELSE Round(( START_DATE - FIRST_VALUE(END_DATE) OVER(Partition By ID, TRUNC(START_DATE) Order By START_DATE Rows Between 1 Preceding And Current Row) ) * 24 * 60, 0)
            END "MINS"
        From
           day_tbl
    )
WHERE
    MINS > 0    -- if you want just ID=40 here you can filter it
--  
/*  R e s u l t :
        ID         RN START_DATE START_TIME END_DATE  END_TIME P_FROM    P_UNTILL        MINS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------- -------- --------- --------- ----------
         4          1 20-NOV-22  00:00:00   25-NOV-22 00:00:00 20-NOV-22 28-NOV-22       7200 
         4          4 26-NOV-22  00:00:00   28-NOV-22 00:00:00 20-NOV-22 28-NOV-22       2880 
        40          1 20-NOV-22  00:00:00   25-NOV-22 00:00:00 20-NOV-22 28-NOV-22       7200 
        40          5 25-NOV-22  18:30:00   25-NOV-22 19:30:00 20-NOV-22 28-NOV-22         30 
        40          6 25-NOV-22  19:31:00   26-NOV-22 00:00:00 20-NOV-22 28-NOV-22          1 
        40          7 26-NOV-22  00:00:00   28-NOV-22 00:00:00 20-NOV-22 28-NOV-22       2880 
        50          1 20-NOV-22  00:00:00   25-NOV-22 00:00:00 20-NOV-22 28-NOV-22       7200 
        50          6 25-NOV-22  23:50:00   25-NOV-22 23:55:00 20-NOV-22 28-NOV-22          5 
        50          7 26-NOV-22  01:30:00   28-NOV-22 00:00:00 20-NOV-22 28-NOV-22       2790
*/
```

Comment: thank you bro for your great code. there is only one bug in the code. for issuer number 50, that 5 mins gap must not get shown in the output because its covered in  11/25/2022 11:00:00 AM   to  11/26/2022 1:30:00 AM. i think i must first merge the time periods with unpivot and then use the result as the input data for the cte.

Comment: @pouryanajafrad:  you are wellcome. Use it whatever way suits you. This is just another way to get you what you need. You can adjust it sny way you need.

Answer (score 0):

i think i could finally finish the job.

**mht_issuer_revoked_call**: this is the table whenever an issuer calls the service, issuerid, startdate and enddate are submitted.

**MHT_ISSUER_MERGED_CALLS**: the requests of issuers are merged and stored in this table.

**MHT_ISSUER_UNIONED_CALLS**: merged calls and input parameters are unioned and stored in this table.

```
create or replace procedure GAP(out_res out sys_refcursor,
                                in_FromDate mht_issuer_revoked_call.startdate%type,
                                in_EndDate  mht_issuer_revoked_call.enddate%type
                                ) as
                               


                                
BEGIN
delete from MHT_ISSUER_MERGED_CALLS;
commit;
insert into MHT_ISSUER_MERGED_CALLS (
  select issuerid,
         start_date_time as start_date,
         end_date_time as end_date
         FROM (
                SELECT issuerid,
                       LAG(dt) OVER(PARTITION BY issuerid ORDER BY dt) AS start_date_time,
                       dt AS end_date_time,
                       start_end
                FROM (
                       SELECT issuerid,
                              dt,
                              CASE SUM(value) OVER(PARTITION BY issuerid ORDER BY dt ASC, value DESC, ROWNUM) * value
                                WHEN 1 THEN 'start'
                                WHEN 0 THEN 'end'
                              END AS start_end
                    FROM mht_issuer_revoked_call UNPIVOT(dt FOR value IN(startdate AS 1, enddate AS - 1))
                    )
                WHERE start_end IS NOT NULL
              )
WHERE start_end = 'end');
commit;
delete from MHT_ISSUER_UNIONED_CALLS;
commit;
insert into MHT_ISSUER_UNIONED_CALLS
(
  Select ISSUERID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By ISSUERID Order By START_DATE) "RN",
         START_DATE "START_DATE",
         To_Char(START_DATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') "START_TIME",
         END_DATE "END_DATE",
         To_Char(END_DATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') "END_TIME", 
         in_FromDate "P_FROM", 
         in_EndDate "P_UNTILL", 
         (END_DATE - START_DATE) * 24 * 60 "MINS" 
    From (
           Select *
           From ( 
                  Select issuerid   "ISSUERID",
                         STARTDATE "START_DATE",
                         ENDDATE   "END_DATE"
                  From MHT_ISSUER_MERGED_CALLS
                  Union ALL
                  Select issuerid,
                         case
                           when in_FromDate >= Min(STARTDATE) then Min(STARTDATE)
                           else in_FromDate
                         end,
                         case
                           when in_EndDate <= Min(STARTDATE) then in_EndDate
                           else Min(STARTDATE)
                         end
                  From MHT_ISSUER_MERGED_CALLS
                  GROUP BY issuerid 
                  Union All
                  Select issuerid,
                         case 
                           when Max(ENDDATE) <= in_FromDate then in_FromDate
                           else Max(ENDDATE)
                         end,
                         case
                           when in_EndDate <= Max(ENDDATE) then Max(ENDDATE)
                           else in_EndDate
                         end
                  From MHT_ISSUER_MERGED_CALLS
                  GROUP BY issuerid)
           Order By ISSUERID, START_DATE ASC, END_DATE ASC
           )
);
COMMIT;
open out_res for
select ISSUERID,
       START_DATE AS START_DATE,
       SELECTED_END_DATE AS END_DATE,
       MINS AS GAP_MINUTES
from
   (
   Select ISSUERID,
           RN,
           START_DATE,
           trunc(start_date),
           START_TIME,
           END_DATE,
           END_TIME,
           P_FROM,
           P_UNTILL,
           FIRST_VALUE(END_DATE) OVER(Partition By ISSUERID, TRUNC(START_DATE) Order By START_DATE Rows Between 1 Preceding And Current Row) as Selected_End_Date, 
           CASE
             WHEN RN = 1 Or RN = Max(RN) OVER(Partition By ISSUERID) THEN MINS 
             ELSE
              Round((START_DATE - FIRST_VALUE(END_DATE)OVER(Partition By ISSUERID, TRUNC(START_DATE) Order By START_DATE
              Rows Between 1 Preceding And Current Row)) * 24 * 60,0)
            END "MINS"
    From MHT_ISSUER_UNIONED_CALLS
    )
 where mins > 0
 and START_DATE >= in_FromDate and END_DATE <= in_EndDate;
END gap;
```